# How to resolve 403 Forbidden on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, lamp

On a fresh install of ubuntu 12.10, I installed the lamp stack via: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`, and `phpmyadmin`.  Then I `sudo chmod 777 /var/www` to be able to openly copy and change files in the `www` folder. I have two issues:

The first is, when I restart the Apache server I get:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

The second when I goto `localhost` in my browser I get the "It Works!", but when I go to `localhost/newsite` I get a 403 error.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to configure apache to serve your `newsite`. Read any apache howto that explains `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Is `newsite` a subdirectory of `/var/www`? If so, does `www-data` have read access to `newsite` and its contents?

Answer (score 1):

In your httpd.conf add:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Then restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to configure you host name as well. This would be done via the hostname command and altering /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname (for ubuntu, other distros are different). For more details see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart